# Reading file .txt from folder to other folder give error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello Guys this is my project tree:

```
C:.
├───data
│   └───path
│           name.txt
│
└───Resources
        get.py
```

I need to read text from name.txt file.

I add this code in `get.py`:

```
class path():

    with open('data/path/name.txt', 'r') as file:
        path = file.readline()
        print(path)
```

this not working I see this message error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JOHN\Desktop\New folder\Resources\get.py", line 1, in <module>
    class path():
  File "C:\Users\JOHN\Desktop\New folder\Resources\get.py", line 3, in path
    with open('data/path/name.txt', 'r') as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/path/name.txt'
```

Comment: If you are not passing a full pass, it is assumed to be relative and in your current directory there is no `data` folder. Either put the full path, or something like: `../data/path/name.txt`

Comment: the problem is I need to use it after convert script to .exe by pyinstaller

Comment: Your **Current Working Directory** is `...\Desktop\New folder\Resources`. Is this the output of running from pyinstaller .exe?

Answer (score 1):

If you start the filepath with a name, it will continue from the working directory (the directory of the python file if you're running in IDLE).

If you want to specify an absolute path on windows, add `C:/` to the beginning, so with your example:

```
open('C:/data/path/name.txt', 'r')
```

Comment: the problem is I need to use it after convert script to .exe by pyinstaller

Comment: It should still work so long as the text file stays in the same path. If you want to make it work regardless of where you move it, I'd recommend putting your exe and assets in one folder, then just moving the folder. From there, you could use `open('Assets/name.txt', 'r')` and it would work no matter where it is so long as the assets folder and exe stay in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the full path `C:/data/path/name.txt` or relative `../data/path/name.txt`.

Comment: the problem is I need to use it after convert script to .exe by pyinstaller

Comment: Can you receive the path of the file as a argument in your script?

Answer (score 0):

To use a relative path (as you're doing now), you need to modify your relative path so that it begins one level up. Try this:

`open('../data/path/name.txt', 'r')`

Comment: the problem is I need to use it after convert script to .exe by pyinstaller